# Hyperelliptic Curve (Liu's Book)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $Y:=\mathbb{P}^1_k$ and $X$ a hyperelliptic curve. We working with the definition 4.7 from Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" (page 288)

[image]

Namely there exist ***finite separable*** map $\pi:X \to Y$ of degree $2$.

I have a ***question*** about the tagged step in the proof of Lemma 7.4.8:

The rational point $y_0$ of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ defines a Cartier divisor (resp the corresp invertible sheaf $O_Y(y_0)$) and let $D:= \pi^*y_0 \in Div(X)$ it's pullback under $\pi$.

Denote by $O_X(D)$ the corresponding invertible sheaf to $D$ and the take into account that the author uses the notation $$L(D)=H^0(X,O_X(D))$$.

My question is why under giving setting we have an inclusion

$$H^0(\mathbb{P}^1_k, O_{\mathbb{P}^1_k}(y_0)) \subset H^0(X,O_X(D))$$

as stated in the excerpt?

My idea was to use the fact that adjunction between $\pi^*$ and $\pi_*$ gives rise for morphism of $O_Y$ modules

$$O_Y(y_0) \to \pi_* \pi^* O_Y(y_0) =\pi_* O_X(D)$$

My question is if and why in this setting this map is injective? If this would be true then the left exact $H^0(-)$-functor would preserve the injectivity and we are done.

Or has Liu here a more simple argument in mind? since Liu hasn't mentioned that in the excerpt above that makes me to assume there is a more easier reason for this inclusion

Comment: Maybe I am confused with something basic. I feel Liu is just trying to use some kind of "pull back of global section" type of argument. The use of adjunction isomorphism is nice, but may not be necessary.

Comment: I think that he works consistenly with pullback concept introduced on page 262 (see lemma 1.33 & def 1.34 )